# Get line number in log handler

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I'm writing my own logging [Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) for Java and I'd like to insert the line number of the log message to my output.

Here's my current attempt without the line number:

```
public class ConsoleHandler extends Handler {

    private static final String SEVERE = "SEVERE";

    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        // Add time and location of the message
        Date d = new Date(record.getMillis());
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).format(d);

        output.append(time + ": " + record.getSourceClassName() + "."
                + record.getSourceMethodName() + "\t\t\t");

        output.append(record.getLevel() + ": " + record.getMessage());

        switch (record.getLevel().getName()) {
        case SEVERE:
            System.err.println(output);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
    public void flush() {}
    public void close() throws SecurityException {}
}
```

I searched the interface of [LogRecord](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html) but could not find out in which line the message was logged.

**Edit:**
I adapted the code linked in jmehrens' answer; this method returns the stack frame of the logging class from which I can get the line number and the file name:

```
private StackTraceElement getCallerStackFrame(final String callerName) {
    StackTraceElement callerFrame = null;

    final StackTraceElement stack[] = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
    // Search the stack trace to find the calling class
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
        final StackTraceElement frame = stack[i];
        if (callerName.equals(frame.getClassName())) {
            callerFrame = frame;
            break;
        }
    }

    return callerFrame;
}
```

Usage:

```
final StackTraceElement callerFrame = getCallerStackFrame(record.getSourceClassName());

if (callerFrame != null) {
    final String fileName = callerFrame.getFileName();
    final int lineNumber = callerFrame.getLineNumber();
    // This creates a link to the line when used in Eclipse
    output.append("(" + fileName + ":" + lineNumber + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no LogRecord (JDK1.4 - JDK1.7) method to get the line number.  If no thread handoff is occurring in your handler or upstream you can create a new [Throwable().getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) and use the [java.lang.StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) API to get the line number.

Example code can be found in the JavaMail API at [MailLogger.inferCaller()/isLoggerImplFrame()](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger.java?rev=601).  If you have to deal with thread handoffs, then you would have to log the line number as a log record parameter.  Keep in mind that computing the callsite is expensive in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this code:

```
StackTraceElement e = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
e.getLineNumber();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the frame with index number two was not the class that logged the message. I think that's because I use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).